# How to check replication lag/delay & replication factor in apache cassandra 3.0.1 (Clustered Environment)

Tags: cassandra

Our environment consist of 4 nodes and 2 DC's, is there any way to check replication lag/delay and replication factor for each node. Apache cassandra version is 3.0.1. 
Using nodetool status command shows

```
Datacenter: DC1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.16.17.20  9.44 TB    256          ?       bbc3763a-e776-4459-9592-e787d5058f59  RAC1
UN  172.16.17.21  9.38 TB    256          ?       cb13d791-a051-49ae-9d8d-fa7079511f25  RAC1
Datacenter: DC2
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.17.17.21  9.41 TB    256          ?       98ce6bf7-11ae-498e-8af5-3e938384369a  RAC1
UN  172.17.17.20  9.38 TB    256          ?       bb5dda41-f1a4-438e-9d74-7990afe5362f  RAC1
```

Answer (score 0):

Replication factor is set for each keyspace. So you can get the replication factor using cqlsh with command `describe keyspaces`

Sorry I didn't understand what you meant by replication delay.

Hope it helps!